# What 22 AWG wire to use for wrapping?

Tags: wire

I'm repairing a receiver and among other things I have to replace some broken wire wraps.

The existing wires are too short for reuse and I can't find any 22 AWG solid conductor wire on the market specifically for wire wrapping, only 24 AWG and up.

Can I use regular hook-up wire with good results and if so what specific kind of wire should I look for? I would appreciate if anyone can give me some advice on this.

Comment: [This is a cable.](https://www.amazon.com/Monster-20-Feet-Speaker-Discontinued-Manufacturer/dp/B00005T3FX/ref=mp_s_a_1_12?keywords=cable+monster&qid=1559942350&s=gateway&sr=8-12)  [This is a wire for wire wrapping.](https://www.amazon.com/Electronix-Express-27WK30WWR100-Insulated-Spools/dp/B01CK9GZV6/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?keywords=wire+wrapping+kit+electronics&qid=1559942468&s=gateway&sprefix=wire+wrapping+kit+el&sr=8-3)

Comment: Yes, I have a good 22-24 wrapping tool from OK Industries.

Comment: Just making the difference clear.  In your question, you consistently wrote "cable" when you were discussing "wire."

Comment: Yes, I thought they are synonymous, hookup cable - wrap wire. But you are correct I mean wire.

Comment: It's a typical mis-translation I see from German speaking people all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Making 22 ga wire wrap connections is not something I'd want to try (and I did wire-wrap for decades - still do, sometimes). As has been mentioned, you'd need a special bit for a wire wrap gun. But that's not the reason I'd avoid it. Wrapping solid 22 ga around a .025 square post will require a *lot* of torque to make the bends small enough. I'd worry about keeping the tool straight as the wrap process occurs.

Instead, I'd suggest you simply solder a piece of 22 ga hookup wire lengthwise on the pin, then slip a piece of heatshrink tubing over the joint and apply heat.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a tool for wrapping wires of that size? It's very specialized equipment that was used for mass manufacturing in a certain era, and without the correct tool, it's unlikely that you can produce wraps with the required tension for reliable connections.

Even with the correct tool, repairs might be "iffy" — it was really a one-time-use technology. Once a terminal has been wrapped and then unwrapped, the nice square edges required for a good, gas-tight connection are now somewhat blunted.

You should probably just use ordinary hookup wire to make repairs to that kind of equipment, and solder the connections. It won't be strictly "authentic", but at least it will be functional.

Comment: They actually do make (and still sell) 22AWG wire wrap tools. No 22AWG wire wrapping wire though. Is there any make-or-break reason kynar insulation and silver-plate is used for wire wrap wire?

Comment: @DKNguyen: Yes, I know "they" do. I'm asking if the OP has one.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread.

Comment: @DKNguyen: And you're thinking of the AWG30 wirewrap wire used for prototyping (and limited manufacturing of) logic circuits. That's actually much newer technology than what the OP is asking about. The tough kynar insulation protected wires from unwanted connections with the sharp edges of nearby terminal pins.

Comment: So there's an even older version of wire wrap than wire wrap? Was not aware of that.

Comment: Your point is well taken. Now the original wrap was made at the bottom of fairly tall terminals. Maybe I could wrap around the unused section with good results.

Comment: I still have spools of AWG30 wire wrapping wire from OK Industries which I used in the 1970's (and my wire-wrapping tools, as well.) If it is "newer technology" then the older stuff must be from the 1960's, I guess.

Comment: @jonk: Yes, it was a technology used for consumer electronics for a brief period after point-to-point wiring became too labor-intensive and before PCB manufacturing became cost-effective and reliable enough. If you look it up on Wikipedia, evidently it is still used in a few niche industries for wire-to-board connections when they don't want to bother with a connector.